# Библиотеки для создания нейронных сетей

Tags: нейронные-сети

Подскажите, какие существуют готовые библиотеки для разных ЯП, на базе которых можно писать свои нейронные сети.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самые передовые пакеты с большими наработками в нейросетях:

1. [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) - C++ (native), Python (native), Java (3rd parties)
2. [DLIB](http://dlib.net/) - C++ (native), Python (native)
3. [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) - C++ (naive), C (native), Java (native), Python (native), .NET (3rd parties)
4. [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org) - C++ (naive), C (native), Java (native), Python (native)
5. [Keras](https://keras.io) - Python (native)

Все пакеты с открытым кодом, имеют хорошую документацию и множество примеров, открыты для расширений.
Есть и другие пакеты.